# How can I mount a dm_crypt device during boot, it fails all the time

Tags: linux, debian, boot, encryption, dm-crypt

**EDIT: Problem solved, i updated from Debian 6.0.6 to 7.0.0, everything works now!**

I have a complex problem at booting. Basically, I have a debian apache box, as a music server in my home network. The root, swap and data hard drives are dm_crypted. The booting should look like this:

1. GRUB
2. Ask root pass phrase
3. Setup swap fs(gets random pw at boot)
4. Booting continues
5. Ask data passphrase
6. Booting finishes
7. Server is accessible via http & SSH

Some logs:

[fstab](http://pastebin.com/ujmi28Xv)

[crypttab](http://pastebin.com/U70T9ya5)

[update-initramfs](http://pastebin.com/TyiXezBV)

[/var/log/boot](http://pastebin.com/AU7Nd5P1)

`uname -a` returns the following:

> Linux linux-server 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Sun Sep 23 10:07:46 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux

debian version: `6.0.6`

Version of cryptsetup: `2:1.1.3-4squeeze2`

What I did:

- I ran `update-initramfs -u -k all -v`
- I can mount the device with `cryptsetup / mount` after boot.

I think the problem is that the external hard drive is not available to the system between step 4 & 5, so `cryptsetup` fails, mount fails, `fschk` fails and the boot process switches into emergency mode.

Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT: Problem solved, i updated from Debian 6.0.6 to 7.0.0, everything works now!**

Comment: Nice to have the complete logs! Unfortunately I don't see the cause of the error. Debian stable, testing, unstable? If not stable, what version of the kernel and of cryptsetup?

Comment: It is debian 6.0.6 stable. It is really stange cause it mounts swap and /, asks me for the / password and i can mount "sdb1" / "sdb1_crypt" with cryptsetup and mount later.
cryptsetup is version 2:1.1.3-4squeeze2 
kernel is version 2.6.32-5-amd64 x86_64

Comment: Can you uncomment `set -x` at the top of `/lib/cryptsetup/cryptdisks.functions` and try again? This should give us a debugging trace, hopefully it'll be easier to understand what's going on.

Comment: Here it is: [Click](http://pastebin.com/wHzrk6fT)

Comment: Ah, got it from the trace. You somehow deleted the `#` at the beginning of the first line of `/etc/crypttab`, so `<name>     <device>  <pass>       <options>` is being parsed as an entry, which causes the not-very-robust script to bomb out. I think fixing that should make your script bootable, so I'm voting to close this question as “too localized”. If that's not enough to fix it, post the new trace.

Comment: [here](http://pastebin.com/hT0UhMFR) it is, device not found, but is is there and i can mount it later!

Comment: yes i can mount it after boot, but it seams empty now?!

Comment: There may be some other problem then. Does it work if you deactivate the device, then run `cryptsetup` manually? What does `file -s /dev/sdb1` show, and `file -s /dev/sdb1_crypt` after activating it?

Comment: Soo, i just ran /etc/init.d/cryptsetup start, it mounted my hdd. I also mounted it manually with cryptsetup and mount.EDIT: [Click](http://pastebin.com/bjGZT3Ps)

Comment: Did an fsck: [Click](http://pastebin.com/24tVByyf)

Comment: Really strange: Did a reboot, device still does not get unlocked during it, same log as above, but after mountig it manually, the files are again there! It seems that /dev/sdb1 is not availible while cryptsetup / cryptsetup-early is called during boot. Thank you for your help so far!

Comment: still not working.. what can i do now? do you need a new log?